# [JMeter]How to test the maximum number of threads that a PC can generate

Tags: jmeter, load, performance-testing, load-testing, threadgroup

I am trying to perform load testing on a single API endpoint.

Using JMeter, I need to benchmark how many threads I can generate using my local machine and existing internet connection before some crash, system instability or bottleneck occurs.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could benchmark and report that?

I am using apache-jmeter-5.0 on Windows 7.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on:

- Your machine hardware specifications
- Your machine software ([32-bit or 64-bit OS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-32-bit-64-bit-operating-systems/) and [JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589057/does-java-64-bit-perform-better-than-the-32-bit-version))
- The nature of your JMeter test (response time, request and response sizes, number of [preprocessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors), [postprocessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions))
- JMeter configuration. Being a normal Java program [JMeter needs to be tuned for high loads](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

So you can measure it as follows:

1. Make sure to monitor operating system baseline health metrics (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, Swap) on JMeter side. The majority of operating systems have built-in tools for this, however if you don't have administrator account - collecting metrics might be tricky, in this case you could use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
2. It would be also good to monitor JVM metrics like Heap usage and GC frequency/time using i.e. [JVisualVM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jvisualvm.html)
3. Start your test with 1 user and gradually increase the load until the usage of CPU, RAM, etc. starts exceeding i.e. 90% of total available capacity. When it happens - see how many virtual users were online using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) plugin - this is **how many users you can mimic for particular this test on particular this machine**. If anything changes - you will need to re-do the assessment.